# Ссылка на символ в строке и изменение строки

Tags: c++

Сразу оговорюсь, вопрос чисто теоретический, без практического применения. 3 примера кода:

1)

```
std::string s = "abc";
char& c = s[0];
c = 'A'; // OK, s == "Abc"
```

2)

```
std::string s = "abc";
char& c = s[0];
s += "def";
c = 'A'; // Error: UB, s+="def" 'kill' c reference
```

3)

```
std::string s = "abc";
s.reserve(100);
char& c = s[0];
s += "def";
c = 'A'; // ??? OK (s == "Abcdef") or UB???
```

Цитата из Джосаттиса "Стандартная библиотека С++. Справочное руководство":

> Для того, чтобы избежать ошибок ..., следует зарезервировать
>   достаточную емкость до того, как будет инициализирована ссылка...

Собственно, вопрос, **с точки зрения стандарта С++ 11 3-й пример кода корректен?** (с точки зрения стиля - плохо, я понимаю).

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, корректен, но конечно нужно найти соответствующую часть стандарта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [п.21.3.1.1/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.require#4) черновика Стандарта вызов не-const функции-члена кроме `operator[]`, `at`, `front`, `back`, `begin`, `rbegin`, `end` и `rend` может приводить к инвалидации ссыллок/указателей/итераторов на объекты строки (символы). В данном случае вызывается модифицирующий `operator+=`.

Т.о. инвалидация (и как следствие - UB) возможна несмотря на присутствие вызова `reserve`.

Comment: а что согласно стандарту _обязан_ делать вызов `reserve`? Что угодно на усмотрение реализации?

Comment: @pavel `reserve` [увеличивает ёмкость](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.capacity#11), или уменьшает (но это не обязательно). При этом мне кажется, что пункт про инвалидацию должен бы включать условие, что если модификация не привела к перераспределению памяти (т.е. `capacity` не изменился), то и инвалидации быть не должно. Вроде как к этому мы и стремимся, когда резервируем заранее память. Однако, это в Стандарте не написано. А есть однозначное упоминание того, что я написал в ответе. Т.е. инвалидация возможна.

Comment: В стандарте сказано, что `+=` имеет тот же эффект, что и `append`. Документация на `append` [говорит](http://eel.is/c++draft/string::append#8) «replaces the string controlled by `*this` with a string of length `size() + n`», то есть про `capacity` ничего.

Comment: @alexolut, в стандарте всё правильно написано, то, что Вы упоминаете привело бы к ограничении реализации. К примеру, если мы введём такое условие, то уже не получится сделать так, чтобы при `reserve` никакого выделения памяти не происходило, а оно бы происходило лишь при попытке добавить элемент.

Comment: @ixSci, про ограничение реализации что-то не понял. `reserve(n)` обязан обеспечить `capacity >= n` после вызова. Так? Мне кажется логичным, добавить в Стандарт фразу, что `если capacity в результате вызова модифицирующей функции-члена не изменился, то и инвалидации ссылок не будет`. Собственно при перечислении списка "кроме" как раз об этом и речь, но в Стандарте ограничились именно списком функций, а не поведением этих функций в зависимости от переданных аргументов.

Comment: @alexolut, да, `reserve` обязан обеспечить `capacity`, но про память там нет ни слова. Поэтому мы можем виртуально «выделить» память, т.е. возвращать увеличенный `capacity`, но при этом не выделять новой памяти, а выделить её лишь тогда, когда «прижмёт». Насколько это полезно? Понятия не имею, может и вообще бесполезно, а может и полезно будет — суть в том, что стандарт старается дать максимальную свободу в реализации сущностей, при этом давая некие гарантии. `reserve` это типичный optimization hint, на который не стоит возлагать больших надежд, кроме одной — потенциальная минимизация выдел...

Comment: ...ений памяти.

Answer (score 7):

А почему он должен быть некорректен? Вопрос нужно ставить по-другому: почему во втором случае случается UB. А случается оно потому, что буфер, на символ в котором указывает ссылка `c`, при расширении строки может быть уничтожен. В третьем же случае буфер остаётся прежним (по крайней мере до тех пор, пока новая длина строки не превышает его размеров).

Comment: Как раз по 2-му случаю вопросов нет, классическое UB, т.к. зависит от имплементации. Может сработать, может закрэшить программу. А по 3-ему примеру вопрос в том, гарантирует ли стандарт сохранность ссылок на элементы строки при изменении строки, при условии достаточного размера буфера.

Comment: Стандарт с вами не согласен.

Answer (score 4):

Второй и третий случай абсолютно равнозначны, с точки зрения стандарта,— оба они *могут* породить UB. С практической точки зрения, ни один из этих случаев к UB не приведёт, ни на одной из популярных реализаций стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Почему второй вариант не может привести к UB на практике? Я считаю, что может, т.к. по причине оптимизации коротких строк до вызова `+=` может использоваться внутренний буфер строки, а после - уже произойдет выделение памяти в куче, и как следствие ссылки побьются.

Comment: Я могу поверить насчёт третьего, но не понимаю, почему для второго не возникает проблем. Ведь буфер может быть переаллоцирован? Или вы ссылаетесь на подробности точной стратегии реаллокации буфера?

Comment: @alexolut, потому что в SSO буфер явно больше 6.

Comment: @VladD, потому что SSO(Small string optimization) используется сейчас везде

Comment: Может быть для конкретных размеров строк из вопроса и не приведет, но это ходьба по очень [тонкому льду](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JPlUUwaxSYBSsbF9).

Comment: @alexolut, вопрос вполне конкретен, по моему. И я на него вполне конкретно ответил.

Comment: @ixSci, только вот из-за опечатки, второй вариант вообще порождает ошибку компиляции :)

Comment: И всё же, акцент вопроса ТС на том, что размер склеенной строки не превышает числа, переданного в `reserve`, а не на размере исходной строки и добавки к ней.

Comment: @alexolut, в первом и втором примере нет `reserve` вообще, откуда тут на нём акцент? В целом, я не понимаю зачем устраивать тут прения. Вы сделали свой ответ, я свой.

Comment: @ixSci ТС в вопросе делает акцент именно на третий случай (т.е. с `reserve`), даже жирным шрифтом выделено. Вы тоже тоже в ответе ссылаетесь на второй и **третий** примеры кода.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string s = "abc";
// s.reserve(100);
char& c = s[0];
for(;s[0] == c;)
{
    s += "def";
    ++c;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Этот код (и код с раскоментаренной строкой `reserve`) ясно показывает, что в первом случае неприятности наступают гораздо раньше.

Но, в зависимости от того, какой именно объем выделяется строке изначально - может быть и наоборот.

Но, как мне представляется (нет под рукой стандарта), третий код все же корректен, в то время как второй - нет.